# when i preess home button there are so many icons are there .i have one icon of my application.how to set image on that icon

Tags: iphone

when i preess home button there are so many icons are there .i have one icon of my application.how to set image on that icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend [this](http://dustinyonak.info/?p=19) tutorial by Dustin Yoniak. It shows every step needed from creating an icon to making it the icon for your app.

Answer (score 0):

just save the image you want to set as icon image with name icon.png. It will automatically take the image as icon image.